# ReturnUrl is always null in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a return url send after a user logs in:

e.g.

```
/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=%2fToDoItems%2fCreate
```

However, the value in the controller isn't binding.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("SignIn")]
public ActionResult SignInConfirmation(UserCredentialsModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

Also, the `Request.QueryString` is empty (bar the `Length`).

How do I bind the query string params to the controller?

As per below, I've tried capitalising the parameter name:

```
public ActionResult SignInConfirmation(UserCredentialsModel model, [Bind(Include = "ReturnUrl")] string ReturnUrl)
```

Comment: I believe the query string parameter names need to match the argument names to your controller methods. If you have `?ReturnUrl=...` then try capitalizing the first letter of your argument name, or using a lower case first letter for the query string parameter name.

Comment: I've tried both of those.  `ReturnUrl` and `returnUrl`.  The thing is, it's not even showing in the query string collection.

Comment: You're doing a Post. Post parameters go into the Post's body, not into the query string.

Comment: Model binding is not case sensitive! You need to add more code - your view and the form.

Comment: @GSerg That will be it.  Cheers!

Comment: I stand corrected - [it should work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10454872/11683).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to retrieve **ReturnUrl** from **HttpGet** method, and send it back on postback.

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignInConfirmation", "YOUR_CONTROLLER", 
      new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
      FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))        
{
    ....
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult SignInConfirmation(string returnUrl)
{
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignInConfirmation(UserCredentialsModel model, string returnUrl)
{
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I did.  Just forgot that you couldn't get query string parameters in a POST.

Comment: I though you couldn't include query string parameters in a route?  I thought it would be a pretty neat solution otherwise.